# Как описать функцию член класса которая вовращает указатель на функцию член класса?

Tags: c++

Здраствуйте.
Описать это словами трудно, проще привести простенький пример кода

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class FlipFloper
{
    public:
    FlipFloper(): action(&FlipFloper::flip) {}

    void run()
    {
        action=(this->*action)();
    }

    private:

    (FlipFloper::*)() (FlipFloper::*action)();
    
    (FlipFloper::*)() flip()
    {
        cout << "flip" << endl;
        return &FlipFloper::flop; // возвращаем указатель на flop
    }

    (FlipFloper::*)() flop()
    {
        cout << "flop" << endl;
        return &FlipFloper::flip; // возвращаем указатель на flip
    }

};

int main()
{
    FlipFloper ff;

    for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
    {
        ff.run();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

action - переменная-указатель которая поочередно указывает то на функцию flip то на функцию flop, при создании екземпляра инициализируется значением указателя на flip. соответственно если в цикле вызывать run() то на екран по очереди пойдут строки "flip" и "flop".
компилятор - g++
спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это невозможно сделать напрямую, но есть обходной способ, см. конец ответа.

---

Предположим, у вас есть:

```
struct A
{
    void foo() {}
};
```

И вы хотите дописать внутрь `A` функцию `bar`, которая возвращает указатель-на-член на `foo`.

Это пишется так:

```
void (A::*bar())() {return &A::foo;}
```

Тип расшифровывается так:

`bar`      `bar` - это
          `bar()`    функция без параметров, возвращающая
      `A::*bar()`    указатель-на-член класса `A`, имеющий тип: (
     `(A::*bar())`   ...
     `(A::*bar())()` функция без параметров, возвращающая
`void (A::*bar())()` `void` )

Теперь, пусть вы хотите написать функцию `baz`, возвращающую указатель-на-член на `bar`.

Она пишется так: `void (A::*(A::*baz())())() {return &A::bar;}`. Расшифровать тип предлагается самостоятельно.

Можно заметить, что если функция X возвращает указатель на функцию Y, то тип X длиннее, чем тип Y. Поэтому две функции не могут напрямую возвращать указатели друг на друга.

---

Решение есть - положить указатель во вспомогательную структуру, и из функций возвращать эту структуру.

```
#include <iostream>

struct FlipFloper
{
    struct P
    {
        P (FlipFloper::*ptr)();
    };
    P action{&FlipFloper::flip};

    void run()
    {
        action = (this->*action.ptr)();
    }

    P flip()
    {
        std::cout << "flip" << std::endl;
        return {&FlipFloper::flop};
    }

    P flop()
    {
        std::cout << "flop" << std::endl;
        return {&FlipFloper::flip};
    }
};

int main()
{
    FlipFloper ff;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        ff.run();
    
    return 0;
}
```